# SQL query - memory overload

Tags: mysql

I have this pretty simple SQL query

```
SELECT v.*, u.user_company as company_name, o.`name` as object_name,
o.address as object_address, i.id as installation_id, i.`name` 
as installation_name FROM maintenance as v, users as u,t_local as o,
t_local_objects as i WHERE o.active=1 AND v.done IS NOT NULL
```

The biggest table - `maintenance`, it has about 3k records, the others have around 300, which isn't really that much. When I execute it, I get a memory overload (tried to allocate over 130MB). How to optimize the query?

The tables will grow bigger in time, so it has to be valid for over 10k records in `maintenance`.

Comment: by not using joins, you are implicitly performing a cross join. matching every row of every table against every row of every other table, giving you a total result set of the number of entries in every table in the query, multiplied together. maintenance has 3k, if all the other tables have 1k rows, you have 3k * 1k * 1k rows in the result, or three billion rows - hence the memory usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for JOINS. And btw 3K rows in a table is not much rather it is too less. JOIN the tables and your will get the results quickly.

Soemthing like this:

```
SELECT v.*, u.user_company as company_name, o.`name` as object_name,
o.address as object_address, i.id as installation_id, i.`name` 
as installation_name 
FROM maintenance as v inner join users as u on v.id = u.id
.....
WHERE o.active=1 AND v.done IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your sql query, you should be using joins.

Where do you get a memory load? 
Depending on the type of application which is using this query, you could try:
1. If its a web or desktop app, you could try pagination, for instance, limit records to a range
2. If you are running inside a sql tool such as squirrel or SQL Management studio, I would suggest checking where the error is coming from, is it an error in the tool? You could try setting up a stored proc which gives out results in a range